# Cyclic codes: sparse codewords not orthogonal to the all-ones vector

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Is it true that for any sufficiently large prime $p$, there exists a prime $q\ne p$ and a cyclic code of length $p$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ that contains a codeword of Hamming weight at most ord$_p(q)$ and which is *not* orthogonal to the all-ones vector?

Viewed as an element of $\mathbb{F}_q[x]/(x^p-1)$, the second condition asks that the codeword is not a multiple of $(x-1)$. Here ord$_p(q)$ is the multiplicative order of $q$ modulo $p$.

Numerical experiments give the impression that the above is true for a codeword corresponding to an irreducible factor of $(x^p - 1)/(x-1) \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ (for some prime $q$).

Comment: As motivation for the condition on $\mathrm{ord}_p(q)$, observe that if $q$ has order $s$ mod $p$ so $p$ divides $q^s-1$ then $x^p-1$ has a factor, say $g(x)$, of degree $s$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$. Now if the Hamming weight of $g(x)$ is $s$ or less, we're done. But in the worst case $g(x)$ has Hamming weight $s+1$, so this method fails. So it seems to me the real question is: when is there a prime $q$ such that one of the $(p-1)/\mathrm{ord}_p(q)$ irreducible factors of $1+x+\cdots+x^{p-1} = (x^p-1)/(x-1)$ in $\mathbb{F}_q$ has Hamming weight at most its degree, i.e. at most $\mathrm{ord}_p(q)$?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I agree with the observation. The numerics seem to suggest that your reformulation has a positive answer. But the type of codeword I’m after is allowed to be a multiple of an irreducible factor (provided 1 is not a root). That might make the problem easier.

Comment: Instead of positive answer I meant to say that the answer might be “when p is big enough”.

Comment: One way this could work: choose $q$ so that $p$ divides $q^2+q+1$ but not $q-1$. Then $(x^p-1)/(x-1)$ splits into cubic factors in $\mathbb{F}_q$. Each factor splits as $(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^q)(x-\zeta^{q^2})$ in a cubic extension field $\mathbb{F}_q(\zeta)$, so has norm $(-1)^3 \zeta^{1+q+q^2}$; since $p$ divides $1+q+q^2$ this is $-1$, and the cubic factor in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is $x^3 + ax^2 + bx - 1$. Now if we could choose the cubic factor to have $0$ trace, we'd get a generating polynomial of Hamming weight $\le 3$, as required.

Comment: I am not completely sure if I understand what you mean by that the cubic factor has zero trace. This sounds a bit related to showing that if p does not divide $t = $ord$_p(q)$, then the  trace Tr$_{\mathbb{F}_{q^t}/\mathbb{F}_q}$ has a primitive $p$'th root of unity as a root. If there is a $q$ for which this is true, then that would work since the trace has "Hamming weight" $t$ and is not zero mod $p$ at 1. Is this indeed related to what you suggest?

Comment: I think I used 'trace' in a rather confusing way. All I meant was that if we could pick a cubic factor with $a=0$, then that would work.

Comment: Stupid question is $q<p,$ or $p>q,$ or either is possible?

Comment: The examples I've seen all have $q<p$. But I don't know if $p>q$ is impossible.

Comment: @MarkWildon: I agree that that would work. I guess more generally you maybe meant the trace of a primitive $p$'th root of unity $\alpha$? If ord$_p(q) = t$, then if I'm not mistaken, the coefficient of $x^{t-1}$ in the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ will be zero, and so this minimal polynomial will work.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, or I am misunderstanding. For a small example, take $p=7$ and $q=2$, so $\mathrm{ord}_7(2) = 3$ and $x^7-1 = (x+1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$. Each cubic factor has as its roots $\zeta$, $\zeta^2$, $\zeta^4$ for some primitive $7$th root of unity (since $p$ is prime, any $p$th root of unity except $1$ is primitive). Moreover both factors are primitive in the sense their roots generate the extension field $\mathbb{F}_{2^3}$. But $x^3+x^2+1$ has a non-zero coefficient of $x^{3-1}$.

Comment: Yes you’re completely right, sorry. I should have said that the coefficient of $x^{t-1}$ is the trace of $\alpha$.

Comment: Incidentally I just found a paper of Cohen (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X90902154) on primitive elements with arbitrary trace. (There are a number of later works showing more general results.) I wonder if this can be adapted to elements of order $p$.

Comment: Are only interested in the minimal cyclic codes? For if we can use large cyclic codes the question becomes trivial by the cheating example of the universal code. That is cyclic and contains the word $x$ of Hamming weight one :-)

Comment: This doesn't sound like what I'm after. I am not sure what minimal and universal cyclic codes are to be honest. Is my question perhaps ill stated? I do want the codeword (polynomial) to have a $p$th root of unity as a root.